# Code positioning

Tags: tex-core

Does Latex allow the true and false statements to be placed on the same line ?

```
 \IfNoValueTF {#5} { \hspace{0.5cm} } { \ (#5) \par\smallskip }
```

rather than

```
\IfNoValueTF {#5} 
  { \hspace{0.5cm} } 
  { \ (#5) \par\smallskip }
```

Comment: Your new name is disappointingly boring!

Comment: Did you even try it?

Comment: It seems to work.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz  Quite contrary, its cleavage is perfect. ;)

Comment: The name does not even have a symmetry axis, neither horizontal nor vertical. How can it be perfect?

Comment: You can find it in hydrothermal veins.  Very interesting.  It is monoclinic with silver in it.

Comment: A new line is usually treated as a space.  OTOH, extra spaces can accumulate and show up as unexpected indentation.  Extra spaces between arguments are ignored, but not inside nor afterwards.

Comment: I can see now that `\IfNoValueTF` is just another function that takes arguments.  Meaning that the way I use it is quite valid.

Comment: why are you asking now surely you have established white space handling is eol is a space or ignored if ExplSyntaxOn.  once again you provide no test file

Comment: One never knows what secrets might come up.  But I am progressing with this Latex bit by bit.

Comment: I remember discussing those spaces.  I will include it in my notes.

Comment: What does one use to introduce a space, Have been using ` \ ` in `{ \ (#5) \par\smallskip }`. Perhaps there is some better way.

Comment: as you have already been told `{ \ ` makes two spaces so normally you would use `{ ` unless in code not shown you change the white space parsing.